# How to generate integer numbers in such a spcific range?

Tags: javascript

I store a game map in a 2D array. And I have a little problem adding new objects into it. The thing is I have a specific cell (the red one) and I need to place another dot in a random cell in a blue area around the red dot.

[image]

The new cell should be at least 4 cells away from the red dot but the maximum distance is 7. I tried to generate random coordinats for a cell dot like this:

```
var new_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance - max_distance * -1)) + max_distance * -1;
if (Math.abs(new_y) > min_distance) {
    var new_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance - max_distance * -1)) + max_distance * -1;
        if (Math.abs(new_x) > min_distance) {
```

But it only generates cells in red areas and never in green areas.

[image]

Also I tried this:

```
var a = Math.round(Math.random());
var b = Math.round(Math.random());

var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance - min_distance));
var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance - min_distance));

var new_x = (5 + d1) * Math.pow(-1, a);
var new_y = (5 + d2) * Math.pow(-1, b);
```

But this does absolutely the same. I have no idea how to generate new coordinats in a such specific range. Need your advice!

Comment: Should the chances of a coordinate being inside any of the squares in the blue be equal? That is, every coordinate should have an equal chance of being chosen?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep! Equal chance. It's like choosing a random cell in a square excluding a square in the middle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random coordinate anywhere inside the blue borders, then retry if it's within the inner white area. The below will generate coordinates such that at least one of X or Y is in the range of 0-2 or 12-14 - possibly both, but never neither:

```js
const max_distance = 7;
const min_distance = 4;

// eg, for upper of 7, generate random number between 0 and 14, inclusive
const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance * 2 + 1))

// maxInnerEdge: the number before which an x or y would be valid
// here, 2, because an x or y of 0, 1, 2 are valid
const maxInnerEdge = max_distance - min_distance - 1;
// minOuterEdge: the number past which an x or y would be valid
// here, 12, because an x or y of 12, 13, 14 are valid
const minOuterEdge = (max_distance * 2) - min_distance + 1;
const valid = () => (
  x <= maxInnerEdge ||
  y <= maxInnerEdge ||
  x >= minOuterEdge ||
  y >= minOuterEdge
);
let x;
let y;
do {
  x = rand();
  y = rand();
} while (!valid());
console.log(x, y);
```

Same thing, but with 6 and 3 instead of 7 and 4, resulting in random coordinates such that at least one is within the range of 0-2 or 10-12:

```js
const max_distance = 6;
const min_distance = 3;

// eg, for upper of 7, generate random number between 0 and 14, inclusive
const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_distance * 2 + 1))

// maxInnerEdge: the number before which an x or y would be valid
// here, 2, because an x or y of 0, 1, 2 are valid
const maxInnerEdge = max_distance - min_distance - 1;
// minOuterEdge: the number past which an x or y would be valid
// here, 12, because an x or y of 12, 13, 14 are valid
const minOuterEdge = (max_distance * 2) - min_distance + 1;
const valid = () => (
  x <= maxInnerEdge ||
  y <= maxInnerEdge ||
  x >= minOuterEdge ||
  y >= minOuterEdge
);
let x;
let y;
do {
  x = rand();
  y = rand();
} while (!valid());
console.log(x, y);
```